# Select rows comparing two column value in ormlite while using raw query

Tags: android, database, android-studio, sqlite, ormlite

I have the following database table

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Order_Details")
public class DB_OrderDetails {

@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private int id;

@DatabaseField()
private int order_id_from_order_table;

@DatabaseField()
private String medicine_code;

@DatabaseField()
private String medicine_name;

@DatabaseField()
private String medicine_type;

@DatabaseField()
private int number_of_units_ordered;

@DatabaseField()
private String generic_name;

@DatabaseField()
private String manufacturer_name;

@DatabaseField()
private double ordering_cost;
... }
```

I am using ormlite for my local db operations. i want to get the result for

```
SELECT * FROM Order_Details WHERE (medicine_code='xxxx' AND manufacturer_name='yyyy')
```

and want to get the result returned in

```
List<DB_OrderDetails>
```

can anybody suggest me a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object of the **Where** class to build your query.

```
List<DB_OrderDetails> list;
try {
        Dao<DB_OrderDetails, String> dbOrderDetailsStringDao = dbHelper.getOrderDetailsDao();
        QueryBuilder<DB_OrderDetails, String> queryBuilder = dbOrderDetailsStringDao.queryBuilder();

        Where where = queryBuilder.where();
        where.eq("medicine_code", "xxxx");
        where.and();
        where.eq("manufacturer_name", "yyyy");

        PreparedQuery<DB_OrderDetails> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
        list = dbOrderDetailsStringDao.query(preparedQuery);
} catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I've also edited a portion from your answer to match it with my requirements